# no difference in predict between lm and lmer

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have read several posts here on CV, in which mixed model data were plotted this way (using `cake` dataset):

```
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
mod <- lmer(angle ~ recipe + temp + (1|replicate), data=cake)
newdat <- expand.grid(recipe=unique(cake$recipe),
              temp=c(min(cake$temp),
                     max(cake$temp)))
lmer.pred <- predict(mod, re.form=~0, newdata=newdat)

lmer.plot <- ggplot(cake, aes(x=temp, y=angle, color=recipe)) + geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=lmer.pred))
```

However, recently I realized that we could get the same values with a `lm` model:

```
mod2 <- lm(angle ~ recipe + temp, data = cake)
lm.pred <- predict(mod2, newdata = newdat)
lm.plot <- ggplot(cake, aes(temp, angle, color = recipe)) + geom_line(data = newdat, aes(y=lm.pred))
```

My question is whether `lmer.plot` is an accurate illustration of the linear mixed model? The `cake` data contains repeated measures (`recipe`) so `mod2` and `lm.plot` seems wrong, and, by extension, `lmer.plot` would also be wrong. However, several posts suggest using plots like `lmer.plot` to illustrate linear mixed model data, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 2):

For the random-effect model you made the predictions with `re.form=~0` so you've set random effects to zero, in such a case the only part that you consider is `angle ~ recipe + temp`, i.e. the same as in fixed-effects model. If you look at `summary(mod)` vs `summary(mod2)` you'll see that the fixed effects parameters are nearly the same, hence nearly the same predictions. Your random effects model assumes random intercepts for `replicate`'s so the difference between the models would be just that the regression lines for each `replicate` would be "shifted" by the intercept. To see the difference between models, show the regression lines for different `recipe`'s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tim, but then the question is why is it common to represent mixed model data in this way? Isn't `mod2` plainly wrong, since it violates assumptions of linear models? But it is not uncommon to see the likes of `lmer.plot` suggested here in CV.

Comment: Could you show me how you would illustrate `mod`?

Comment: @locus apparently you saw people showing plots with zeroed-out random effects because this was what they intended to show. Here you zero-out random effects and wonder why you don't see their contribution in the plot:  you don't see it, because you used plot that does so. How to plot random effects as well? Just make `newdata` have all the columns as your data and *don't use* `re.form=~0`.

Comment: As about `mod2` being "wrong": the only difference between the two models is that `mod` assumes additional source of variability between `replicate`'s; if you don't account it, you assume that there is single intercept and all the variability is just residual variance. The second model ignores important source of variability, but is not "wrong". If you look at the diagnositc plots `plot(mod2)`, you'd see that they look rather ok.

Comment: what I meant by "wrong" is that I thought (fixed-effects) linear models required independent observations, which isn't the case here since we have a repeated measures (`recipe`). So, for all intents and purposes, `mod2` is statistical inaccurate, isn't it?

Comment: "All models are wrong." Also the model you use is not correct since from what I see from the description, the effects are nested, what is not considered by `mod`. The answer to your question remains the same.